# window.open() not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've searched many links for my query. But couldn't get the one I want.
Am using in `window.open(url, '_blank')` in my script on click of button(am not using any html here, I want it to be on button click only). Its working in Chrome, IE8. I want to open a new tab in the same window in **IE11**. I don't want to do any settings in Internet Options of IE. Because the script has to work in every system, if I go with manual settings the script won't run in all the systems where ever I test.
Is there any bug with IE11 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window.open() itself opens in new tab, Just remove "_blank".
Use the below code.

```
window.open(url);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. as I was checking in Chrome, it didn't opened a new window for my script.

Answer (score 0):

window.open syntax is like :

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures])
```

So the second parameter is windowname, not the target sepcification.

Please refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Comment: In the link that you added says "This name can then be used as the target of links and forms by specifying it as the target attribute of <a> or <form> elements.", so the WindowName used to create the popup could be used as target by A or FORM tags