# window.open opening new tab instead of new window in IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-11

I have an ASP.NET application which uses window.open.
It opens a tab instead of a new window. This happens in IE 11. In IE 8 it works fine.

Since we are moving to IE 11 we want this to work on IE 11 too.

```
var url = "reportViewer.aspx?reportname=" + $("#hfReportName").val() + "&schoolDistrict=" + district
            window.open(url, "_blank");
```

I have done my research and [here is what I found.](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?298537-windows-open()-function-opens-new-tab-instead-of-new-window-in-IE11&s=8cdd7fedc8128c2fccf5f9c578be515d)

I am not sure if that is the right way of doing this. I want to do this through code. Any idea how I can do this. Let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to omit the second parameter? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119867/window-open-not-working-in-ie11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to override user preference and open a new window?

Answer (score 0):

The `_blank` is for open in new tab. Just remove the second parameter of `window.open`, which is optional, it will work fine.

Use it like this : `window.open(url)`

Answer (score 0):

"_blank" is the default for window.open. You don't need it. Your link is opening in a new tab because of a browser setting, not code.  Go to Internet Options, General, Tabs. There is a section, "When a pop-up is encountered". You would have to change this to "always open pop-ups in a new window".