# HTML Javascript window.open() and href _blank doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, href, window.open

I encountered another issue with the tool I'm trying to create for my team.
I have this "NEW" button within a form that opens a new tab and opens the same html file.
The button works with Chrome, but for IE version 11.0.9600.18449 which what we have at work I get an Invalid Argument error for the window.open() command line.
I tried creating a function for window.open() and calling it via onClick for the New button but still getting the same Invalid Argument error. I also tried doing it via EventListener, but getting the same and the error always follow the file name line.
I tried creating a Hyperlink on the "Call Template" on html line 4, now this one doesn't work too, and I get this statement from Dev console

"DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337"
"File: XBSCallTemplateBetav1x6.htm"

If you need the whole code to look at, you can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/ct70mL9w/

```
    <label><input class="INNewExec" onclick="window.open('XBSCallTemplateBetav1x6.htm');" type="button" value="New" /></label> <!-- New Button -->
```

I haven't coded for about 3 years and so please go easy on me :)

Comment: There is no need to pass a second argument to `window.open`. The `_blank` that you have there isn't doing what you think it is anyway as the new window always opens in a new browser tab.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I have removed that too. And just left ('url') in there. It still didn't worked @ScottMarcus

Comment: I don't think your issue is with `window.open()` per se. I think the issue stems from the file you are opening. Have you tried this: `window.open("http://cnn.com");`?

Comment: it worked for actual websites. Window.open('http/https://...') works fine. The error only occurs when a file name is in there. Is there a loop in the codes to resolve this like to make IE11 think it's http but a local file?

Comment: Again, I don't think the presence of a file name or not is the issue (any resolvable path to a file is fine). I think the issue is that once the browser attempts to parse your (XBSCallTemplateBetav1x6.htm) particluar file, there is something in that file that is causing the error.

Comment: I get you point now. Earlier version of this html had that button working.

Comment: Try opening that file directly and look at the console to see if you get an error.

Comment: Earlier version of this html had that button working and then I added more codes and eventually the button or should I say the code stopped working. I'll try to rewrite the code and see what code disabled back and forward caching

Comment: I did what you advised. Same informational statement showed in Console "DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337"

Comment: Then, this proves that the problem is not with `window.open()`, it is with the file that you are trying to open.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It's with the Restrictions in our Work Environment. The file and code fully works if I import the saved file from my home computer to my office one. I encounter the issue if the file is edited and saved in our workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It's with the Restrictions in our Work Environment. IE at work has a list of Local Intranet sites that it allows, 'New Call Template.htm' is allowed so I figured that the File name of my version of the template should be the same and it WORKS. But If there's a workaround to name the file anything aside from requesting to include the template to the allowed intranet, please do advise. Thanks mates!

Answer (score 0):

Take away the '_blank' because in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119867/window-open-not-working-in-ie11) article, it states that chrome and other browsers already open in a new tab when using no second parameter.

> window.open() itself opens in new tab, Just remove "_blank". Use the below code.
>
> `window.open(url);`

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I have removed that too. And just left ('url') in there. It still didn't worked